# Is this question on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

[Can I use an induction cooker to restore silica gel's water absorbency?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14071/is-it-possible-to-use-induction-cooker-to-replace-oven-in-heating-silicon-gel)

This question was posted recently - apparently after the OP was pointed to our site from the Electronics site.

Is it on topic?

NOTE: I've closed it as "off topic" under the assumption that it isn't suitable.

Comment: I don't see how it has anything to do with home improvement.

Comment: @Tester101 - neither do I, but I wanted to be 100% sure I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not so sure... when I first saw the question you linked to, I thought he was talking about *silicone gel*, that you often see for cookware like muffin tins, cake pans and so on, which would make it off topic.  Other household uses of silicone make less sense to me: I can't imagine anyone would scrape up their discolored silicone caulk, heat it and reapply it to their bathtubs, for example.

But take a look at this other question by the OP for context:

[How do I know if the canister of silica gel or strips of vapor corrosion inhibitor have lose its effectiveness in absorb moisture?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/12723/22)

It seems he's asking about a *silica gel* dessicant to prevent tools from rusting, which I think makes it on-topic.  It just needs to be heavily edited, which I've just done.